# QGIS panel will not dock (or too small and will not undock)?

Tags: qgis

I detached my Layers panel from QGIS (version 3.6.2) and now it will not dock.

I have already tried double clicking the top bar, this works for every window/panel apart from Layers. It simply will not go back.

Additionally if you look below the toolbar, this is the Vector Toolbar. I cannot get it to undock or resize to even show me the icons, they are lost forever.

Is there a config file or setting I can delete to revert to defaults for this?

[image: Layers Window]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting QGIS and then seeing if the windows can be docked again?

Comment: Yes, I did! just now and magically the layers panel lets me dock, however vector toolbar remains faulty... I can see the problem ... if I use the dotted lines I can detach it from the top toolbar and float, but it is about 32x32 pixels and will not resize, it looks like there are no items in the toolbar, they have all been deleted...?

Comment: Sorry, fixed that one. Your answer was correct.

Comment: Vector toolbar is also empty for me too (same version), at the moment anyway. So you can disable it by going to `View > Toolbars`.

Answer (score 1):

Following comments, if you close QGIS, then reopen, it (usually) lets you redock. Must be a bug in 3.6.2 or earlier.

Answer (score 1):

In case of this type of bug, it sometimes helps to toggle the specific toolbar or panel. You can show and hide toolbars and panels in a variety of ways:

- View menu > Panels *or* Toolbars
- right click on a blank part of any toolbar (IE not on a button)
- right click on the top bar of any panel (next to the panel name)
- View menu > Toggle Panel Visibility, hotkey combo `Ctrl` + `Tab`
- View menu > Toggle Map Only, hotkey combo `Ctrl` + `Shift` +`Tab`

  - **Warning**: this *hides all the menus* (including the View menu), so you need the hotkey combo to turn off Map Only mode!